# Capture URL with query string as parameter in Flask route

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way for Flask to accept a full URL as a URL parameter?

I am aware that `<path:something>` accepts paths with slashes. However I need to accept everything including a query string after `?`, and `path` doesn't capture that.

```
http://example.com/someurl.com?andother?yetanother
```

I want to capture `someurl.com?andother?yetanother`. I don't know ahead of time what query args, if any, will be supplied. I'd like to avoid having to rebuild the query string from `request.args`.

Comment: The general form for those is "query parameters", and you can use [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data) to get at those.  However, I'd expect those to be *valid* query parameters; normally, you'd see `http://example.com?foo=bar&baz=quux`.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Restructure your URI to accept a single query parameter that will catch the entire value. `http://someapi/?full_param="someurl.com?blah?blah?blah"`.

Comment: What I am doing is a test of a URL response from various locations.  Unfortunately some URLs I am testing require me to pass the variable in order to get proper response.  However I do not know ahead of time what this variable is, and therefore I can't preplan for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `path` pattern will let you capture more complicated route patterns like URLs:

```
@app.route('/catch/<path:foo>')
def catch(foo):
    print(foo)
    return foo
```

The data past the `?` indicate it's a query parameter, so they won't be included in that patter. You can either access that part form `request.query_string` or build it back up from the `request.args` as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way routing works, you will not be able to capture the query string as part of the path. Use `<path:path>` in the rule to capture arbitrary paths. Then access `request.url` to get the full URL that was accessed, including the query string. `request.url` always includes a `?` even if there was no query string. It's valid, but you can strip that off if you don't want it.

```
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path=None):
    return request.url.rstrip("?")
```

For example, accessing `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello?world` would return `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello?world`.